# Gulpfile watchTask only in first run

Tags: gulp

so i started yesterday with gulp 4.0
so when i start gulp he only compile my sass to css in the first run. idk why
this is my

```
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');


// File paths
const files = { 
    scssPath: '/scss/*.scss',
    cssPath: '/css/'
}


function scssTask(){    
    return src(files.scssPath)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) 
        .pipe(sass()) 
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer(), cssnano() ]))  
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) 
        .pipe(dest(files.cssPath)
    ); 
}



function watchTask(){
    watch([files.scssPath], 
        scssTask
        );  
}

exports.default = series(
    scssTask,
    watchTask
);
```

LOGS;
[22:36:57] Using gulpfile D:\xampp\htdocs\project\gulpfile.js

[22:36:57] Starting 'default'...

[22:36:57] Starting 'scssTask'...

[22:36:57] Finished 'scssTask' after 13 ms

[22:36:57] Starting 'watchTask'...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that what you want is really:

```
const files = { 
    scssPath: './scss/*.scss',
    cssPath: './css/'
}
```

Note the `.` added to the start of  each value.  To make them relative to the location of the `gulpfile.js`.